# JBPM 5.4 LocalTaskService scope in Spring

Tags: spring, jbpm

I am using JBPM 5.4.0.Final with Spring 3.0.6

I am using local task service.

What should be the scope of **org.jbpm.task.service.local.LocalTaskService** if it is declared as a spring bean ? Can it be a singleton ?

**tasks-context.xml:**

```
<bean id="internalTaskService" class="org.jbpm.task.service.TaskService">
        <property name="systemEventListener" ref="systemEventListener" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="htTxManager" class="org.drools.container.spring.beans.persistence.HumanTaskSpringTransactionManager">
        <constructor-arg ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="springTaskSessionFactory"  class="org.jbpm.task.service.persistence.TaskSessionSpringFactoryImpl" init-method="initialize" 
                                                depends-on="internalTaskService">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="jbpmEMF" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="htTxManager" />
        <property name="useJTA" value="true" />
        <property name="taskService" ref="internalTaskService" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="taskService" class="org.jbpm.task.service.local.LocalTaskService" depends-on="springTaskSessionFactory">
        <constructor-arg ref="internalTaskService"></constructor-arg>
    </bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is, how many instances do you need. If you have just one client of that application you can just create it singleton, it shouldn't affect the behavior. Let us know if you have any troubles with it.

Cheers

Comment: Thanks. Till now I haven't faced any issues. I have declared the LocalTaskService as singleton.I am injecting the LocalTaskService bean into my other stateless services (spring beans).